# WebView: Inherit/get the function of Default Browser (Android)

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to inherit/get the function of the user's Default Browser? For example, the user's default browser is CM Browser, and it has adblocker, etc. Can I use the function of that in my WebView? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use CM Browser as your rendering WebView application. Android use  [Android System Web View application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en) as rendering WebView. Currently Firefox developing rendering engine for Android, its called [GeckoView](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView). If you need to use adblock that CM Browser has, then you need to open your URL using CM Browser.